# Can't require operative

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use:

```
var operative = require('operative');
```

in my JS code that's running in a webbrowser.

Obviously, with the current release of [operative](https://github.com/padolsey/operative), it doesn't work as browserified code because there's no `module.exports` used in the library.

Someone raised the issue and [provided code](https://github.com/padolsey/operative/issues/39) to fix it, but the fix doesn't work. I tried fixing the fix myself [here](https://github.com/kvdb/operative/commit/f0baa830fb8403455c699863f559603894636e7a), but I don't have a good enough understanding of both operative, nor the require concept.

So, what's the right way of 'upgrading' a library such as operative to make it work with require?

Comment: *a library such as operative* - IOW, any NodeJS library. So the question, that I'm pretty sure has already been answered, should be "how to use nodejs libraries in the browser".